I want to remotely start, stop or recycle apps in the IIS app pool through an app
Hello fellow explorers,
As the title states i want to make an app so i can remotely start,stop or recycle my apps in the apppool.
Why?

Where i work we have a simple server which we all acces with the same user. We all have multiple apps running there and sometimes we need to stop the app. But someone is working serverside and gets thrown out in the progress. He logs back in and yeah you get the picture.

What did i do?

I wanted to show off a little an quickly make a form which gives you back a list of apps. And when you select one, you can choose to start, stop or recycle. Boy did that take me on an adventure.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace AppPoolRegulator
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
private const string \_Servername = "NameOfServer";
private const string \_Username = "NameOfUser";
private const string \_Password = "WordOfPass";

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BuildForm();
        }
    
        private void BuildForm()
        {
            int x = (this.ClientSize.Width - pbImage.Width) / 2;
            pbImage.Location = new Point(x, 12);
            x = (this.ClientSize.Width - lbApps.Width) / 2;
            lbApps.Location = new Point(x, 124);
            lbApps.Items.AddRange(GetAllApps().ToArray());
        }
    
        private List<string> GetAllApps()
        {
            List<string> apps = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(_Servername))
                {
                    foreach (Site site in serverManager.Sites)
                    {
                        foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application app in site.Applications)
                        {
                            apps.Add(app.Path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return apps;
        }
    }

}

My adventure
I wrote that little block of awesome and found myself not connecting. I tried it without OpenRemote and got some nonsense error, when running it in admin mode i dont get any errors and i get a "/" back.
Which is probably normal because i am not running any apps locally.
So i try the openremote thingie and it gives me a null error upon calling up serverManager.Sites.
Most posts i see on the internet are a couple of hundred - 5 years old. So no recent info to be found.
Any advice or help or explanation on how this actually works is welcome.

To create a remote management tool for your application pools, you need to ensure that the remote server is configured to allow remote management and that the credentials you're using have the necessary permissions.
